# Flyback Transformer selection for Active Balancer on Automotive BMS project

Tags: transformer, automotive, flyback

I am designing an automotive prototype using an active balancer (LTC3300-1) where all the components must meet the AEC-Qxx standard.

I managed to find all components compliant to AEC but its imposible to find flyback transformers. The datasheet recommends some PartNumbers but none of them are compliant. For example the 750312504 from Wurth: [750312504 Transformer](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/750312504.pdf)

I know what specs the transformer should have. Could be possible to contact a supplier and ask for a custom solution? I am impressed that it is so hard to find trasformers compliant to AEC-Q200.

Comment: _”Could be possible to contact a supplier and ask for a custom solution?”_ That’s the standard solution for 99 % of all SMPS transformers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even for the automotive one? By asking a supplier for custom automotive grade components (AEC compliant), it means i will have to pay a huge extra cost, right?

Comment: Ask LINEAR / AD. If they made a demo board from this components, they should know something about. I would be surprised if each component in a car is compliant to AEC-Q200.

Comment: 750312504 meets IEC/UL/EN60950-1, maybe is even more demanding than AEC-Q200.

Comment: Does AEC even extend to custom wound products? I’m not in automotive. Cost varies. Tooling is usually very low or zero if you go with a standard bobbin and core size. How many are you making?

Comment: Try https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/fcacd5b8-fe6f-4892-9001-f3f5d42e2cf3/aec_brochure.pdf